# MySql: Create an efficient computed column

Tags: mysql

I have an already large query that selects product information. Everything is fine until the point where I try and create a computed column.

The idea is that the products table contains a price column, but before a price change is committed I create a new_price column like so

```
CASE
WHEN id = 1 THEN (value from $newPrice array)
WHEN id = 2 THEN (value from $newPrice array)
...(ect sql statement continues to be generated from array)...
ELSE NULL END AS new_price
```

Everything is fine when working with a small newPrice array but when it contains 1,000 + values the CASE statement becomes very large and the query takes a long time.

Is there a better way to be doing this without physically inserting the temporary new_price data while still creating a new_price column for sorting purposes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't assign to the `new_price` column, it compares it.

Comment: Sorry bad example, the SQL is WHEN ID=1 THEN 9.99 ect.

Comment: You could insert the new data into a temp table and join it

Answer (score 0):

You can join all the `$newPrice` values into a comma-delimited string, then use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to access a particular value in it.

```
$newPrices = implode(',', $newPrice);

...

SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('$newPrices', ',', id), ',', -1) AS new_price
```

Another solution would be to insert all the new prices into a temporary table, and then join with it.

Comment: Very nice idea if `id` has sequential values. It won't work very well for ids like 32412,543872,833882.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at generated columns? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html